# Python variable names in Greek alphabet

Tags: python, scientific-computing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unicode identifiers in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649544/unicode-identifiers-in-python)

Just checking, but I'm assuming there is no way whatsoever I can write a Python program with lines such as:

```
σ = 5.67e-8
j = σ * T**4
print j
```

Wouldn't it be nice to extend the syntax to accept Greek symbols for variable names? I believe it can make the code more readable, it's better IMHO than having to write "sigma = 5.76e-8...".

If Python's syntax doesn't support that, is there any IDE/editor that could accept it, and then transparently transform 'σ' to 'sigma' just before running the program?

Comment: It is possible in Python 3 but not Python 2.  However, you should think carefully about whether this is a good idea, as it can make your code hard to read if people try to edit it using a computer/font that doesn't support those characters.

Comment: What version of Python are you using? I use Greek characters all the time--as identifiers and otherwise--in 3.x (since 3.x deals with unicode in a more easily accessible fashion).

Comment: OK, I'm using python 2.7. I'm not sure I want to switch to Python 3...

Comment: I suggest sticking with Python 2.7, for multiple reasons, including the fact that 3.3 removes `long`-type objects (hence all integers take the same amount of memory). On a more related note, you should use `sigma` or `delta` (or whichever letter you want to use spelled out) instead of the actual letter for it. It is easier to read and also less likely to raise syntactical errors for those who do not have those fonts installed on their computers.

Comment: Yeah, I'm happyg with Python 2.7. I'm "scared" of 3. Oh well. I might roll out a simple "run" program (in Python of course), that'll take my source with Unicode Greek letters and simply replace the Greek symbols with "sigma" in Latin encoding. That should be trivial to do, actually. Hope I can somehow combine it with iPython 'run'.

Comment: @eyquem: "there are no variables in Python": that's the silliest myth.  It's confusing and counter productive, please don't spread it around.  What you mean is that variables in Python work differently than variables in C.

Comment: @Ned Batchelder You should better explain what are variables in Python according to you, instead of pretending to know what I mean. Show a variable in Python, please.