# Syntax Error with Japanese(Kanji)

Tags: python-2.7, encoding, utf-8

I'm new to programming. Attempting self-instruction. I've come across many errors already, but always been able to find the answer or figure out the issue with enough diligence, but this is just throwing me for a loop(see what I did there?).

Can someone please explain what seems to be an impossible error?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/5LUFkyN.png]

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what's going on? Where is that error message coming from? I'd expect the one line of code you show to give an error as your Kanji name isn't a previously defined variable, but I've never seen a popup error dialog like the one you've shown.

Comment: Yes, of course! So, firstly I've been unable to use Kanji characters since I started learning Python a few weeks ago. I understand that I need to declare some encoding in order for it to properly print them. I almost never work in the IDLE environment, I usually work in Notepad++ and then execute from Powershell, but it always just gives me a syntax error. So, I decided to use IDLE and it's giving me this error msg saying to add a line that was present already(verbatim) in my code. That's my point of confusion.

Comment: Is your question about why you're getting an error in the first place, or why IDLE gives you an unhelpful error message? The answer to the first is simple, [you can't use Unicode in identifiers in Python 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649544/unicode-identifiers-in-python) (you can, with some limitations, in Python 3). I have no idea what's up with the IDLE error message, and I can't reproduce it.

Comment: It was about why IDLE was telling me to add something to my code that was already present, exactly as it was recommending. I see now that it was due to, as you said, trying to use Unicode in Python 2 when that isn't possible. Thank you very much! That clears it up and I see the problem now, perfectly. <3!