# unicode identifiers without sacrificing python 2 compatibility

Tags: python, unicode

I have a python units package. I want to have both `Å` and `angstrom` be two aliases for angstroms, so that people can use whichever one they prefer (`Å` is easier to read but  `angstrom` is easier to type). Since unicode identifiers are [forbidden in Python 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2649560/1272672), the `Å` option will obviously only be available in Python 3. My question is: Is there any way to have a single source file that works in both Python 2 and Python 3, and has this variable defined in Python 3 only?

The naive solution `if sys.version_info >= (3,): Å = angstrom` does not work, because Python 2 raises a syntax error.

Comment: Haven't tested, but you may be able to hide it in an `exec`.

Comment: What about `globals()['Å'] = angstrom`.  You probably don't even need your `sys.version_info` for that one.

Comment: Interesting idea by the way . . .

Comment: @mgilson - `globals()['Å'] = angstrom` seems to work great, if you add it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, I don't encourage anything other than ascii characters for variable names...  However, this is an interesting idea since the angstrom symbol actual has it's standard meaning in this context so I guess I'm cool with it this time :-).

I think you should be able to accomplish this with:

```
globals()['Å'] = angstrom
```

and this will "work" on both python2.x and python3.x.  Of course, your python2.x users won't be able to reference it in their code without reverting to weird hacks like `getattr(units, 'Å')`, but it won't throw an error either which is the point of the question (I think).