# Python setattr vs __setattr__ UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, setattr

I know that we have to use `setattr` method when we are outside of an object. However, I have troubles calling `setattr` with unicode key leading me to use `__setattr__` directly.

```
class MyObject(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__["properties"] = dict()
    def __setattr__(self, k, v):
        self.properties[k] = v
obj = MyObject()
```

And I get the following content of `obj.properties`:

- `setattr(obj, u"é", u"à")`: raise UnicodeEncodeError
- `setattr(obj, "é", u"à")`: `{'\xc3\xa9': u'\xe0'}`
- `obj.__setattr__(u"é", u"à")`: `{u'\xe9': u'\xe0'}`

I don't understand why Python is behaving with these differences

Comment: I am using Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 14 2015, 16:09:02)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python 2.7?  Ascii identifiers only.  That includes your code in 2) - ascii accent but not .1) - unicode accent.

[Unicode identifiers in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649544/unicode-identifiers-in-python)

3) involves you setting an unicode *key* within a dictionary.  Legal.

Note that __setattr__ is *almost never* meant to be used as you are doing. It's meant to set attributes on an object. Not intercept that and stuff them in a internal dict attribute.  I'd Avoid properties too as a name, confusing with properties in the get/Set sense.

Generally you want to use setattr, not the double underscore variant.  Unlike your opening sentence.

You typically also don't *call* double underscore methods, you define them and Python's underlying data protocol calls them on your behalf.  Bit like JavaBeans get/set implicit calls (I think).

__setattr__ can be tricky.  If you are not careful, it blocks "setting activities" in unexpected ways.

Here's a silly example,

```
class Foo(object):

    def __setattr__(self, attrname, value):
        """ let's uppercase variables starting with k"""

        if attrname.lower().startswith("k"):
            self.__dict__[attrname.upper()] = value

foo = Foo()

foo.kilometer = 1000
foo.meter = 1

print "foo.KILOMETER:%s" % getattr(foo, "KILOMETER", "unknown")
print "foo.meter:%s" % getattr(foo, "meter", "unknown")
print "foo.METER:%s" % getattr(foo, "METER", "unknown")
```

output:

```
foo.KILOMETER:1000
foo.meter:unknown
foo.METER:unknown
```

You needed to have an `else` after the `if`:

```
        else:
            self.__dict__[attrname] = value
```

output:

```
foo.KILOMETER:1000
foo.meter:1
foo.METER:unknown
```

Last, if you are just starting out and unicode is a big deal, I'd evaluate Python 2 vs 3 - 3 has much better, unified, unicode support.  There are tons of reasons you might or might not need to use 2.7, rather than 3, but unicode "pushes towards" 3.

Comment: I finally solved it by calling `encode('utf-8')`before calling `setattr`. Otherwise, concerning the last point, I have the following requirement: be able to access object property "toto" via `obj.properties["toto"]` and also directly `obj.toto`. Thus, intercept `setattr` and `getattr` seems to be the only solution.

Comment: Francais?  The `toto` vs `foobar` gives that away ;-)  *If* you only need to access via obj.toto for *reads* then you can leave setattr alone and instead write a \__getattr\__ that returns obj.properties[attrname].  Overriding \__getattr\__ is common, \__setattr\__ is more special case and needs careful consideration.  I'd have something like my silly example with the k variable names and test for leading `_` in attribute names to allow for normal internal variables.

Answer (score 0):

Python 2 doesn't allow unicode identifiers:

```
>>> é = 3
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    é = 3
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Presumably it's so insistent on this point that you can't work around it as you're trying because `setattr` goes through some processing before calling `__setattr__`. You can show this by inserting a `print` at the very start of `__setattr__`: nothing gets printed, so the issue is not in your code.